# How to trigger an app to fetch data via a REST-Service?

Tags: ios, rest, mobile

I am looking for a way to trigger an app to fetch data from a remote REST-Service. The approach shouldn't require polling.

iOS push notifications doesn't seem to be an option due to the fact that it can be deactivated by the user. However, I may be wrong.

Is there a best practice to get this done?

Comment: Are there user events you can subscribe to?

Comment: Assuming the app is a simple messaging app, so user A sends a message (by uploading it to the server), then user B has to call the REST service to download the message. So, a user event would be "MessageSend". Since i don't have a socket connection (if i would, then its clear how to solve the problem), I don't see a way to have a publish/subscribe pattern here.

Comment: Do you have Restfull web API's?

Comment: Is that you want to build chat application?

Comment: This is really much too broad of a question to give an answer to, especially without knowing full context of what functionality and behaviors you are trying to build into your app.  But at the end of the day, you really only have two options on how you can get data updates into your application.  You have to either push the data into the application (which would necessarily need to rely on functionality provided by the OS/environment for a mobile app such as this because of concerns around backgrouding of the app) or you have to pull the information from the remote service (polling).

Comment: You can achieve calling service from the background even if the app is not in memory. You can use Core Location framework and use the method "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges". This will be automatically called when a new location is available and hence, you can call you server to get the data in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Push Notification is the way to go.

On ios8 and later, push notifications are enabled by default for exactly this reason you want.
You cannot show something to the user (meaning pushes containing a json with an alert will not be shown), but your app is getting the payload and can initiate an action once the push is received.

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:):

> A user’s notification settings control only whether the system
>   displays local or remote notifications onscreen. **Regardless of the
>   notification settings, local and remote notifications are delivered to
>   your app at the appropriate times**.

Comment: thanks, that the app receives push notifications no matter how the end user configured notifications settings is the hint i needed...

Comment: You are welcome @Scholle . Just remember this is for iOS 8 and later!

Answer (score 1):

**Fetching data from restful services**
Hey @Scholle, this can be a done in many ways
1. **NSURLRequest:** by making a network call to NSURLRequest and confirming to NSURLConnetionDelegate protocol methods. Then serialize the JSON response.
in NSUrlConnectionDidReceiveData method

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData      options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", jsonArray);
}
```

2. **AFNetworking** Simply import latest afnetworking 3.0 in your project. And use following code to make a network call with list of arguments.

```
- (void)requestWithURL:(NSString *)url parameterDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)data  requestType:(NSString *)reqType  handler:(NSObject *)handler selector:(SEL)selector{
// Request Type is GET or POST
// handler is set to be self if we want to handle response in selector method defined in same viewController

NSError *error;

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:reqType URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] parameters:nil error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
if (data != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Data is not nil");
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}else{
    NSLog(@"Data is nil");
}



[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {
 //            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [handler performSelector:selector withObject:responseObject];
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            //blah blah
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
        [handler performSelector:selector withObject:responseObject];
    }
}] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the early days of iOS background fetching was impossible. Over time, Apple has relaxed this a little bit, but ultimately they want Apps to be low energy software that performs focused tasks.

I believe it was iOS 5 or 6 where Apple introduced an enhancement where Apps the user uses the most are kept alive for longer. Also the preview of the App in the multitasking carousel can be updated by the system, if the App does a background fetch (for Apps that the user uses the most).

> Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the
>   system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for
>   that content. To support this mode, enable the Background fetch option
>   from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your
>   Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the
>   UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist
>   file.) **Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give
>   your app any time to perform background fetches.** The system must
>   balance your app’s need to fetch content with the needs of other apps
>   and the system itself. After assessing that information, the system
>   gives time to apps when there are good opportunities to do so.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to see how to implemented background fetching with beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use polling nor sockets and I assume that the event time cannot be predicted, I guess the best you can do is to use notifications and frequently warn the user to enable them, the app should cope with the fact that the notifications might not be enabled.

If the fetch is essential for the app I wouldn't discard polling, I would use notifications with the previous approach and fall back to polling if they are disabled.