# Request failed: unauthorized (401) AFNetwoking how can i fix this

Tags: ios, object

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
NSString *URLString = @"http://162.243.9.247:1337/login";
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": @"password", @"baz": @[@1, @2, @3]};
NSMutableURLRequest*request=[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];

manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {

        NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@ ----->%@", response, responseArray[0][@"lfs"]);
        self.fullarray = responseArray[0][@"lfs"];
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: I better suggest you to go through solution suggested to make network call using AFNetworking 3.0.  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919129/how-to-trigger-an-app-to-fetch-data-via-a-rest-service/36011939#36011939

Comment: This `NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": @"password", @"baz": @[@1, @2, @3]};` doesn't seem right to me. The format in the Dictionary  is key:value

Comment: You are sending username and password through http? Seriously? That should be a criminal offence. Every hacker can sniff the password. Please tell us what application you are using so we can avoid it.

Comment: I just saw you are _trying_ to send username and password through http, what you are actually doing is sending the username of a user with the unusual name "password", and no password. So that's secure then. Also an obvious reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure

[image: Make sure that these added in Plist]

**Step for server uploading**

```
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

 NSString *urlType = @"http://162.243.9.247:1337/login";
NSDictionary *param = @{@"email":@"one_user@gmail.com", @"password":@"asdfasdf"};

NSMutableURLRequest*request=[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlType parameters:param error:nil];


[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    } else {

        NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@ ----->%@", response, responseArray[0][@"lfs"]);
        self.fullarray = responseArray[0][@"lfs"];
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: i have changed the dictionary  parameters still it is raising same error

Comment: actually iam getting an error like dis ---request failed eror 401

Comment: @vshnu -- I agree, it is your local URL , can you update the question once , what the parameter u need to pass

Comment: actually they hav provided me lik dis

Comment: If you have a decent server then it will refuse any attempts to login through http :-)